# Jelly Bean Google Voice text-to-speech API?

Tags: android, voice, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Is there a way I can use the text-to-speech from the new Google Voice? In Jelly Bean the pronunciation is really smooth so I was thinking may be there is some kind of API for access to that service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to access the Google Now voice using the Android TTS APIs.
You need to use "KEY_FEATURE_NETWORK_SYNTHESIS" in the "params" parameter for the TextToSpeech.speak() call.

See

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.Engine.html#KEY_FEATURE_NETWORK_SYNTHESIS

and

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#speak(java.lang.String,int,java.util.HashMap)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#speak%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.util.HashMap%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use just the standard TextToSpeech class?

See [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) for usage. You can pass a "engine" string to the constructor. If the JB TTS Engine appears as a different engine you could choose it there. But I assume that the new JB TTS engine is used automatically if you just select the standard TTS engine.

Comment: unfortunately this is not the case, the google now version is much more advanced than the tts provided with android jb. I don't think it can be used.