# Android Jelly Bean (Google Now) text to speech engine not availble for developers?

Tags: android, voice, text-to-speech, android-4.2-jelly-bean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jelly Bean Google Voice text-to-speech API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382621/jelly-bean-google-voice-text-to-speech-api)

I am trying to play around with the google tts api and no matter what I try, I can't get it to sound like it does in "Google Now"'s search results.
Is this not available for use?
does anybody know this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* possible to access the Google Now voice using the Android TTS APIs.
You need to use "KEY_FEATURE_NETWORK_SYNTHESIS" in the "params" parameter for the TextToSpeech.speak() call.

See

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.Engine.html#KEY_FEATURE_NETWORK_SYNTHESIS

and

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#speak(java.lang.String,int,java.util.HashMap)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#speak%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.util.HashMap%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29)

-- 
Fergus Henderson

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'm going to create a small project and host it on google hosting later and link to it for others to view.

Comment: see project example at http://code.google.com/p/simple-jellybean-tts-example/

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing in the jelly bean API makes the "voice" of Google Now available to developers. The TTS will use whatever voice engines are available on the device.

Comment: So the weird thing is that I'm using a text to speech demo I found at http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-using-the-text-to-speech-engine/ which uses the android tts engine and it does not sound like the google now voice... not even close

Comment: Why is that weird? My response explained that there's no basis to have any expectation that the sound would be like Google Now...

Comment: I see what you mean, I thought you meant that by using the Jelly Bean device TTS engine it will use what I thought is the Jelly Bean voice - i.e. the google now voice.
If that is the case, what is google now using as it's TTS engine?